# Sending notification dynamically in android app

Tags: android, android-studio, notifications

I want to send a notification dynamically regarding the availability of the product to a customer in android app.It should check the db whether the selected product is available or not and send the notification to the customer.Can anyone help me to solve this?

Comment: server code. you cant run this on a local device.... or everytime a user load the app, a notification is sent. what db are you using? firebase? use cloud functions.

Comment: is there any other possible way to send  notification from the shopkeeper to a specific customer?